# visual studio 2010 : "ConfigurationGeneral" rule is missing from the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, configuration

I want to compile a 64-bit application using Visual C++ 2010 professional, but I keep getting this error, and I have no idea what to do :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Error: The "ConfigurationGeneral" rule is missing from the project.
```

I've searched this problem on google, but all ideas didn't solve my problem.

Thank you!

I have windows 8.1 Pro 64bits if this information is needed, and I use visual studio 2010 c++ professional.

Edit : tried repairing visual studio professional, but it still doesn't work :\

Comment: Check if there's a `ConfigurationColonel` you can promote.

Answer (score 5):

The VS2010 x64 compilers are missing...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519277/en-us

You need this update:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422

Comment: Upgrade to SP1 removed compilers for some reason. Thank you for the download link.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the language of the Visual Studio GUI recently?

I switched the language of my installation from German to English which resulted in almost the same error message. (except I'm trying to build for Win32) Switching back to German resolved this issue.

It seems that most people experience this when building for x64. So if you didn't change your language [give this a try](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/884d5b10-50dc-4cc1-9c17-f036b73bc637/error-the-configurationgeneral-rule-is-missing-from-the-project?forum=Vsexpressvc).

Answer (score 1):

I have an english version of Windows 2008 R2 and the international setting (Tools/Options/Environment/International Settings) of VS2010 was "Same as Microsoft Windows". After changing it to english and afterwarts to german it solved the problem immediately.

Thanks a lot.